# mtrr log says that my BIOS doesn't use all CPU's?

Tags: cpu, amd-processor

In my dmesg log I see the following lines about my CPU not having al CPU's set up.

```
[    0.211558] mtrr: your CPUs had inconsistent variable MTRR settings
[    0.211559] mtrr: probably your BIOS does not setup all CPUs.
[    0.211560] mtrr: corrected configuration.
```

However, when running lscpu in a terminal I see that all the CPU's are working. What is this?

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 16
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1400.000
BogoMIPS:              7182.25
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             16K
L1i cache:             64K
L2 cache:              2048K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

I'm using a AMD A8-5600K CPU. http://shop.amd.com/en-gb/components/processors/AD560KWOHJBOX

Answer (score 4):

It is saying your bios did not set up the MTTRs on all of the cpus, so the kernel took care of it.

Comment: So, in other words. There is nothing wrong with the hardware?

Comment: @Allard, there is something wrong with your bios, but the kernel is smart enough to work around it.

Comment: Is it possible this is 'just' because the CPUs have multiple threads, so the second thread was not set up correctly by BIOS?

Comment: @LetynSOFT, it may be possible, but speculating about the cause seems pointless.  All that really matters is the bios has a bug, and the kernel compensated for it.  Who really cares what contributed causing the bug?

Comment: sorry but this is a question would inconsistent mtrr settings cause the possibility that I can't boot into most others os's?